# How to BecomeFirstResponder the UiTextField after each UiButton's Enter action in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have `UITextField` & `UIButton`. I want to `becomeFirstResponder` my `TextField` after each Enter action (my Button action) but it doesn't work ! here is my code :

```
[_textfield becomeFirstResponder];

[_textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

[_back addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)backAction:(id)sender
{
    [users addObject:_textfield.text];
    _textfield.text = nil;
    [_textfield becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: In code, where is these target actions added? in viewdidiload, right?

Comment: does this _ _textfield_ is button or textField name?

Comment: - yea it added in viewdidload

Comment: - it's textfield name

Comment: you have a textfield, when user types anything in the field and clicks on the button, the data will get added to an array and the textfield becomes blank. If this is the requirement, the above code is working fine. Please check whether you have connected the IBOutlet correctly.

Comment: when i clicked on Button it's ok and my Textfield becomeFirstResponder again, but when i type and Enter it becomes blank but don't becomeFirstResponder again. and i define them in interface with code not using IBOutlet.

Comment: "but when i type and Enter it becomes blank ", enter means clicking the button, right?

Comment: no it means press Enter on keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "backaction:" add a separate action for textfield.

```
[_textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

And in this targetted method,

```
- (void)dismiss {
[self performSelector:@selector(backAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]}
```

It seems to be working when I tried.

On clicking return, editing gets completed and keyboard resigns. But 'backaction:' will get triggered before that and the keyboard will disappear. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have give textfield delegate to view controller or add code

```
_textfiled.delegate = self
```

Comment: i define it one time in INTERFACE and one time in PROPERTY and give textfield delegate to view controller but it doesn't work yet.